# Crop fal_media images in News extension in TYPO3 8.7.1

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want to crop images in list view. In TypoScript setup I define:

`plugin.tx_news.settings.list.image.maxWidth = 185c`

next, in FLUID templates:

`<f:image image="{mediaElement}" maxWidth={settings.list.image.maxWidth}"/>`

but the image is not cropped to desired width. Instead it's processed in generic width and height. Looks like, when addding **c** both cropping and rescaling are ingored. When I replace **185c** with **185**, the image is properly scaled down to 185px width. Do you know how to enable/debug cropping option?

FYI: I'm using ImageMagic and in Install Tool, Image Handling settings are set properly. I've checked in "Test setup" and writing, converting, scaling images works without problem.

TYPO3 8.7.1, tx_news 6.1.0-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To problem is that `maxWidth` doesn't work with the `c` append. Change `maxWidth` to `width` at the image viewhelper in your fluid code to let the append crop the image.